# How to make 1 of the 4 columns more narrow?

Tags: html, css

I hope you are doing well.

I can't figure out how to make one of my td more narrow than others. In the picture that I've attached below, you can see my + icon is the same size as other columns. I want to make it really narrow and be next to the left column.

[image: Picture]
This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<thead>
      <tr>
          <th><h1></h1></th>
          <th><h1></h1></th>
          <th><h1>TITLE</h1></th>
          <th><h1>TITLE</h1></th>
      </tr>
</thead>

      <tbody>
          <tr style="background-color: #eee;">
          <td onclick="showPleaseHide()" id="trCheck" style="background-color: #eee; transition:box-shadow 0.2s ease-out; text-align: left;">Enrollment Fee</td>
          <td class="plusButton"><span class="down1"><i style="color: orange;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></td>
          <td>US $0</td>
          <td>US $450</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="active" id="hide1">
          <td style="color: white; background-color: rgb(140, 167, 241);"></td>
          </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.container2 th h1 {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.container2 td {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container2 {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   display: table;
   padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container2 td, .container2 th {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;  

}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if it sounds basic, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: well it already is next to the left column, and if you want it to be narrow then set its width to a small px or % of the table. But if you want the plus sign to flow inline with the first column text then just put it in the first column and remove the column it was in

Comment: @zgood I tried to make its width smaller, but I don't know where to make it smaller because I change one thing, everything will change with it.

Comment: make a style around the class you already have: `td.plusButton { width: 10px; }`. Table cells will adjust to always fill out the complete width of the table.

Comment: @zgood I did and it did not even move/change positions.

Comment: @zgood Thanks, I added it to th and it worked

Comment: @zgood please leave an answer and I will mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. I'll share the simplest first:

Just make the + sign in the first column, just add spaces if needed... (I know, very simple).

Like this:

```
<tr style="background-color: #eee;">
          <td onclick="showPleaseHide()" id="trCheck" style="background-color: #eee; transition:box-shadow 0.2s ease-out; text-align: left;">Enrollment Fee  <i style="color: orange;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></td>
          <td>US $0</td>
          <td>US $450</td>
          </tr>
```

Option 2:

Use the already designated "plusButton" class to create less space between the border and the + sign.

HTML:

```
<tr style="background-color: #eee;">
          <td onclick="showPleaseHide()" id="trCheck" style="background-color: #eee; transition:box-shadow 0.2s ease-out; text-align: left;">Enrollment Fee</td>
          <td class="plusButton"><span class="down1"><i style="color: orange;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></td>
          <td>US $0</td>
          <td>US $450</td>
          </tr>
```

That was code from your original example. Now CSS:

```
.plusButton {

    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

I hope this works out fine :)